# Storm input and output possible source

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

I am beginning with Storm. I would like to know that what are possible sources that I can use for my POC? Like Twitter.

Where can write output data after processing with Storm? Like HDFS/Hbase etc.

Comment: Have a look at: http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

Storm can handle *any* source or sink that can be accessed via regular Java/Clojure/... code (if you are willing to do the coding by yourself).

Of course, there are many standard sources/sinks and Storm contains a couple of Spout/Bolt implementation for them: for example there is `KafkaSpout` or `HdfsBolt`. Check out the project as new sources and sink are added over time.